# Allow to enter language specific character from keyboard

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, icefaces

I have one application providing language selection option to user.

I want to implement facility that user are allowed to entering text from keyboard in selected language. e.g. If i select Hindi my application takes an input in Hindi.

I am using JSF(icefaces) and Hibernate.

Is it possible ? How ?

Comment: What do you mean by `If i select Hindi my application takes an input in Hindi.` - that the OS input is changed to Hindi and instead of typing English characters you start typing Hindi automatically? I don't think that's possible, since you'd have to change OS settings (which a Webapp can't or shouldn't be able to do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use language translation javascript function on onkeyup event

you need to include external JS for this as http://www.google.com/jsapi..

please refer this for your reference

http://www.labnol.org/internet/website-translation-with-google-language-api/4367/

may this help u :)

Comment: Your second link help me lot and i am able to translate from english to Hindi.But Google translator does not contain code for gujarati translation. Thanks

Comment: fine,we can also achieve same thing by creating Gujarati virtual keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible. The question is "how much is this?"

Go to translate.google.com and see that they are able to detect writing language automatically. if you are able to do so send the text typed by user using AJAX to server and validate that the text is written in chosen language.

But language detection is not so simple task. It is simple if language uses its unique script. For example Georgian language (as far as I know) uses its own script and no other languages use the same script. You cannot say the same about European languages: they all use Latin letters. In this case more sophisticated methods are required and google does it. BTW You can probably utilize this tranlate.google facility (if they have API). Send typed text to google using AJAX and see which language does it detect. It is not 100% correct but much better that everyone of us can implement himself.

Comment: You are right but Google can't contain API for Gujarati language.